# Open default browser and login with SSL

Tags: browser, autologin

I'm brainstorming a C# project to auto-login to a web portal when a hotkey is pressed. The username and password need to be securely sent to the web portal to login. I have created the hotkey and storage, and retrieval of the credentials, but I'm stuck on how to actually open the default browser and login.

Things I have thought about:

1. Sending hashed values in the URL (HTTP Get). This is great, because I can just call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(loginUrl);`. But, this creates a LONG URL and run the risk of copy and pasting the URL (I don't want the login URL to be portable or reusable).
2. Grabbing the COM object and sending into visible forms the creds, then hitting a hidden submit button. All while the current page shows some 'loading' splash. But, this requires grabbing the COM object of an open browser or creating one based on the default browser and hoping that browser compatibility allows me to access the DOM to set the text in the forms and it the submit button. (all hopefully through SSL, although I'm not sure how that will affect things from my end if at all)
3. I have seen examples on this site using WebRequest and WebResponse. But, do those actually give the commands to the default browser? Or does that make a connection right to the C# program. Becausewhat I really want is to "forward" the credentials to a browser like IE so it can login. Assuming the webpage that I am contacting is HTTPS, then that means I can send unencrypted credentials to the form since they will be secured over the internet? And the end user will not be able to copy the creds since they will be submitted to hidden forms right?

To conclude: I'm looking for a secure way to send credentials to a browser to use to log into a web portal without having to worry too much about browser compatibility.

Thankyou for your time and let me know if I can provide any more information.